# where did the elasticfox add-in go?

Tags: firefox, amazon-web-services

I new development machine and I'm just getting it set up.  I found the S3 organizer through the firefox add-in option, but I can't find the elastic fox --- where did it go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the address has changed since this question was posted.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/elasticfox.xpi

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but [Elastic Fox](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=609) can be found under the tools menu in Firefox if properly installed. If you're trying to install it, you can go to the Elastic Fox page and click the Download button to install the add-on .xpi.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is where is the elastic fox page --- in the past I've been able to get the add-in from the firefox add-in ui directly.

Comment: There is a link to the Elastic Fox plugin page directly in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find standalone versions as well as FF extensions http://elasticfox-ec2tag.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ (xpi / dmg / exe )